# Restkit delete all objects in coredata for a specific object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

Using Restkit and I am not seeing how I go about deleting all the objects (e.g. Shoes) from core data?

I used to use the MSMangedObject+EasyFetching, but it hasn't been updated to RestKit .20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit isn't designed to delete all objects. If you want to do that you should do it manually.

RestKit is designed so that you can ask it to delete any objects matching a fetch request if they weren't returned from the server in the last request. See: [RKManagedObjectRequestOperation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html) in the "Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects" section.

If you just need to get access to the managed object context so you can manually delete objects you can do:

```
[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
```

Comment: I understand that. Please see my reference to NSMangedObject+EasyFetch. This was class used with Restkit to make deleteing object from coredata easy. I made reference to Restkit as they were usually used hand in hand.

Comment: So you'll need to fetch the items you want to delete, loop over them and delete each.

Comment: So how do you go about doing that?  So say I have a class called RestEngine (it holds my access to Restkit), but I am in some viewcontroller how can I get access to Restkits NSManagedObjectContext  from some other viewcontroller?